# How is the recipient's probability of survival calculated in Hamilton's Rule?

Tags: evolution, altruism

This is Question 99 from the 2012 USABO Semifinals Exam:

> Assuming that "snonting" is an altruistic behavior that is maintained due to kin
> selection, consider the following situation:

> A reproductive male, X, lives with his mate near his parents. His other
> siblings are all females and no longer live nearby. Based on your observations,
> you know that X is likely to produce 12 MORE offspring during his life. His
> parents, however, are older and will only produce 3 more offspring during
> their lives. One day, a situation arises where X’s parents have a 50% chance of
> death. However, if X snonts, his parents will survive with 100% probability.
> Given this information, use Hamilton's rule to predict the maximum probability
> of death that X can incur in this situation in order for snonting to be favored.

I calculated the answer based on Hamilton's Rule (*r⋅B>C*), where *r* = 0.5, *B* = (1-0.5)⋅3, and *C* = *x*⋅12. Solving for *x*, I arrived at an answer of 6.25% probability of death for individual X. However, the answer listed on the test is 12.5%, which I assume is arrived at by giving the recipient a probability of survival of 1, instead of an increased probability of survival of 0.5. I am wondering which interpretation of Hamilton's rule is more accurate, or if I have misinterpreted the question.

Thanks!